# Is extending a type to expose an extension method on a private member bad?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

I was recently berated for extending a custom class to expose a LINQ extension method on a private member, say:

```
public virtual T FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return _someDbSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

Some team members told this is bad. The explanation given was something along the line of: since the inner method is an extension method, the outer should be as well.

(Why) is this so bad?

Comment: This isn't an extension method.

Comment: Is that what makes it bad? Why? (Note that the inner FirstOrDefault *is* an Extension Method.)

Comment: Did they disagree on creating the method itself, or the implementation?

Comment: @Gert: The method itself. The explanation given was something along the line of: since the inner method is an extension method, the outer should be as well.

Comment: @Protectorone: No way. That doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Agree, doesn't make sense. Looks like the class is some sort of generic repository? If so, nothing wrong with it. In other types of classes a name like "FirstOrDefault" might be a bit nondescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a major problem in adding a method with the same name as an existing extension method if it 'overrides' the functionality of that extension method, or the signatures aren't compatible with each other (or if the extension method can't be applied to that specific class).

If those rules don't apply, or you do intent to use both of them, it can be really confusing which method is getting called in the end. This may lead to bugs, so I would not advise to use a method with the same name as the extension method.

Comment: I agree, and add that renaming the method is probably in order either way. `FirstOrDefault` only makes sense if the class is logically a collection (but my guess is that its a little more than just that)

Comment: @YoryeNathan: What if the class serves as some kind of collection (maybe it fetches the first line from the db, who knows?). having an method named `FirstOrDefault` is perfectly fine.

Comment: I was just saying that - unless the class represents a collection. The keyword is unless here.

Answer (score 0):

> The explanation given was something along the line of: since the inner method is an extension method, the outer should be as well.

If that was the argument, then that's utter nonsense. Taken to its logical conclusion, we couldn't call any static members in instance members (since extension methods are just static methods with some syntactic sugar to make them look like instance methods on the first argument). Apply that consistently and you'd soon end up with either no static methods at all or no objects at all.

There is a bit of an issue here though:

> public virtual T FirstOrDefault(Expression> predicate)

`FirstOrDefault` is a commonly used extension method. As such we have an idea what it's going to do whenever we call it.

If the class acts as a collection that wraps `_someDbSet` then this method is pointless; we can just use the `FirstOrDefault` that already exists.

If the class does not act as a collection that wraps `_someDbSet` then this method could be confusing, as it wouldn't act as we'd expect the well-known `FirstOrDefault` to act.

If the class is an `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable` and `FirstOrDefault` doesn't do the same thing as the `FirstOrDefault` extension method, then it could be very confusing indeed, because the same member name would produce different behaviour depending on how the object was referenced, and that's only very rarely a good thing.

Conversely though, if we had a `FirstOrDefault` instance method that did the same thing as `FirstOrDefault` would otherwise but did so much more efficiently, then that is a case where having an instance method mask an extension method is a very good thing indeed; there's no behaviour difference as far as the calling code is concerned, just a performance boost that is "free" as far as that calling code goes, as it's written in exactly the same way that it would be anyway.

Comment: It indeed simply wraps the existing `FirstOrDefault`, but on a member that's private. Wrapping it like this exposes it.

Comment: Well yeah, that's what public members are for; to expose operations upon the private state.